MS access average of four values linked to a date and time
How can I combine the temperature values that has been measured every quarter in an hour to just one average value per hour? I want to make a query in MS Access. Can you provide a SQL to do this?



Time
Temperature




21-02-2020 16:29
5,63562


21-02-2020 16:44
5,63562


21-02-2020 16:59
5,63562


21-02-2020 17:14
5,6842




5,63562 is a temperature value?

Construct a DayHour value to group by. Then use AVG to calculate average temp for the group.
    SELECT Format([Time],"yyyy-mm-dd hh:""00""") AS DayHour, 
           Avg(TempReadings.Temperature) AS AvgOfTemperature
    FROM TempReadings
    GROUP BY Format([Time],"yyyy-mm-dd hh:""00""");




DayHour
AvgOfTemperature




2020-02-21 16:00
5.63562


2020-02-21 17:00
5.6842



